# Getting 404 Not Found error after deployment in azure app

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I created a basic PHP file and tried deploying through both FTP and git, where in both scenarios the URL taking to Hostingstart.html. I tried giving `https://<site-name>.azurewebsites.net/index.php`, it takes to 404 Not Found.

Can anyone assist me on this ?

Comment: Which platform you use ? Linux or Windows ?

Comment: https://akrabat.com/running-php-applications-on-azure-app-engine/

Comment: If my reply is useful to you , do you mind me post answer here ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Windows** environment, you need a file named [web.config](https://akrabat.com/running-php-applications-on-azure-app-engine/) like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Pretty URLs to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)

 
<pre wp-pre-tag-1="">
```

If you are using a **Linux** environment, you need a file `.htaccess`, refer to this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig#sample-application-htaccess-file).